# MvxExpandableListAdapter throws an exception

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

i am trying to load MvxExpandableListView with custom Adapter .

```
public class ExpandView : MvxActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ExpandView);
        var list = FindViewById<MvxExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.TheExpandView);
        list.Adapter = new MyCustomAdaptor(this);
    }

    private class MyCustomAdaptor :MvxExpandableListAdapter
    {
        public MyCustomAdaptor(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And i am getting the below exception .

> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: bindingContext is null during MvxAdapter creation - Adapter's should only be created when a specific binding context has been placed on the stack

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know. You haven't set a BindingContext on the Adapter.

Comment: yes but the constructor for MvxExpandableListAdapter doesn't take a binding context

Comment: Yes it does: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/Views/MvxExpandableListAdapter.cs#L21

Comment: Damn  Me ,  i was using an older version of  the package  , Thanks @Cheesebaron